# ubuntu /dev folder restore

Tags: ubuntu, restore

I am a linux fresher. I make a folder /dev/test/ in Ubuntu. When I rebooted the server, the folder /dev/test/ was disappear. Can restore the folder? Why?

Thank you.

Comment: ...why did you create anything under /dev ? You probably shouldn't be poking in the device subfolder without good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device file system in Linux is not a filesystem stored on disk. See this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#devfs). In kernel 2.6 series it is devtmpfs and is managed by udev.

In short the things you do in /dev filesystem do not persist through reboot.